# What is this strange shell? I want to desinstall but don't know its name

Tags: command-line

When I login from the terminal (not XOrg), my computer starts with the weird shell featured in the image below.

[image: weird shell I want to desinstall]

If I click in the Unity terminal icon, It opens with my dear bash shell.

I don't remember when I installed it, but I want to remove it and don't know the package name. Can anyone help me?

This shell has 2  problems:

1. It is very slow to start. When I log into the terminal I usually
   want to solve a problem quickly.
2. All the terminals log me into the
   same shell. Even if I do Alt-F2 and login, I will fall into the same
   session.

Comment: Can you take a better picture?

Comment: What Jan said. I can't read anything

Comment: That looks like the `byobu` terminal enhancement.  To remove it `sudo apt-get remove byobu`

Comment: @Terrance:  you got it. Please answer so I can make it correct. Excuse me everybody for the terrible photo. Wrong upload.

Comment: @neves  Thank you!  Answer has been added.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the `byobu` which is a terminal enhancement that is installed.  More information about it can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_(software)).

To remove `byobu` from your system, type in the following at a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get remove byobu`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just plain old sh to me.  Type this to find out:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: `$SHELL` is your default login shell. Not necessarily the one that is running at the moment.

Comment: But he gets this as his default login shell, so it should be the same....